# How can I safely store gold coins for my game

Tags: python

I am coding a game with python for windows. The game requires players to purchase gold coins at some point. The program will store the balance of this coin to a file but if the user backup this file after purchase, uses the gold coins and then replace the file with the backup, the gold coins would be restored. How can make the program detect this. How can the program know when the original file has been deleted (assuming no connection to the internet)

Comment: Can you just store information about whatever they would have purchased with the coins in the same file as you store the information about the gold coins? Then restoring a backup would also remove their items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the limit to be enforced offline - there's no way around this. You could limit the items / functionality available by making people actually download the code itself as part of the purchase. But there's no way around the user making a full backup. Once you store the state on the client machine, you lose the control. You can only make the cheating hard / complicated to execute, but not prevent it.

You can however prevent restoring coins without making other modifications. By integrating the store of currency and items/whatever, you can ensure that the specific coin maps to some specific other thing. This way the user can change what was bought (revert to backup and buy again), but they can't get infinite benefits.

Comment: what if i can lock the file for copying and only open it when the program is running. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Ozichukwu You can't lock it. Your application can't do anything the user can't, so whatever you do to "unlock" it later, the user can do exactly the same thing.

Comment: this won't work for my use-case but i'll give it the best vote

Answer (score 0):

IMPLEMENTING SAVEGAME ANTITAMPER:

1. Install PyCrypto (skip this if it is already installed)
2. Create a class which will be the storage container (char's name, coins, inventory etc will be stored here). IMPORTANT: NEVER store money and inventory separately!!!
3. When saving, pickle that storage object.
4. Encrypt that save using PyCrypto.Cipher.AES (most trustworthy). Key is, in most cases, `charactername[::-1]`
5. Write it to a file. Tada!

---

***NOTE*** Even encryption is not enough in some cases. If you really wanna protect your saves, use AES + Cython + DeNuvo. However, cloud saves are still safer.

Comment: Still not 100% secure. Better use save cloud (Steam Cloud)

Comment: This is obfuscation, not protection. You can look at the source easily since it's just python. User looks at your source, decrypts the container in the same way, changes what they want, encrypts it again. Tada!